# Golang are package block variables thread safe?

Tags: go

According to the Go spec:

*"The scope of an identifier denoting a constant, type, variable, or function (but not method) declared at top level (outside any function) is the package block."*

Are package block variables thread safe? E.G. If I have a package block variable to store the current user for a web app:

```
var CurrentUser *string
```

Request 1 comes in: Set CurrentUser to "John"
Request 2 comes in: Set CurrentUser to "Fred"

In Request 1 what is the value of CurrentUser?

Comment: Thread safe is usually used to mean that parallel reads or writes won't cause mischief. But I think you're asking for goroutine-local state. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. I thought that was more or less the same thing seeing as go routines use threads behind the scenes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, package variables are not thread safe.

In your example, CurrentUser could change from "John" to "Fred" at any time—although the goroutine handling Request 1 is not *guaranteed* to see the change.

So you need to use a local variable to store any data that is different for different goroutines.

Comment: What I really want to do is create breadcrumbs, without user X interfering with user Y, how do I tweak http://play.golang.org/p/fydmwNmkWU to get it to work?

Comment: You need to keep a separate trail of breadcrumbs for each user. Something like this: http://play.golang.org/p/wANVmCQ5E5

Comment: Option 1 will definitely not work; it has the same problem as the original. Option 2 isn't specific enough for me to say. How long do you want the breadcrumb trails to last? What events should change them?

Comment: After each request the trails can go away, and be repopulated on the next request, no event is going to change them.

Comment: So what is in the trail? Just the path from the URL?

Comment: Yes, for each page request, I want to populate something like this http://getbootstrap.com/components/#breadcrumbs

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44510/discussion-between-andybalholm-and-lee)